# Does anyone still have Ngo's notes from his 2011 class in chicago?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

The class was "Automorphic forms on GL(2)". There used to be rather complete notes @ www.math.uchicago.edu/~ngo/AF.pdf but it seems like the author has taken them down. It would be much appreciated if someone can help me access these again (Should have saved them last time....)

Comment: Professors are often glad to send you stuff like this if you email them and ask for it.

Answer (score 9):

Is this it [**Automorphic Forms on GL(2)**](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~ngo/AF-web.pdf)?

**Update**

Here are some additional note examples in case you wanted to peruse others.

[**Automorphic Forms on GL(2)by Jacquet Langlands**](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woodbury/research/jlnotes.pdf)

[**Automorphic Forms on GL(2)by Jacquet Langlands - Book-like set**](http://www.math.clemson.edu/~jimlb/jacquetlanglands.pdf)

[**Automorphie Forms on Covering Groups of GL(2) - Yuval Z. Flicker**](http://www.math.osu.edu/~flicker.1/xmeta.pdf)

[**Automorphic forms for GL2 over Q - Kevin Buzzard**](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/automorphic_forms_for_gl2_over_Q.pdf)

Regards -A

Comment: I thought the original one is more complete than this 18 page version...But please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is the set of notes, and feel pretty confident given that he says "This is a set of notes for my class "Automorphic forms on GL(2)" in the University of Chicago, Spring 2011". However, you might want to email him and ask to be $100-percent$ sure. I added some other notes examples if you were interested in perusing those too. Regards

Comment: Awesome find! + 1